# add exchange distribution groups to lync 2013

Tags: lync

Is it possible that we can do some settings in Lync server and only these type of Dl ( distribution list ) or address bydefault add in their lync group while the user logged in to their lync account and also search option will be work for all contacts. 
anything either its through registry hacks,GPO or else you know.

Any assistance or advice would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to control distribution group display in Lync clients? I believe it is possible to do this, if you build a custom Lync client and use the ContactManager.BeginAddGroup. I don't believe it is possible to do this to clients using the Lync Server APIs.
Perhaps there is a way on the server-side using one of the Exchange APIs.